# How to change the delimiters in a javascript string

Tags: javascript

First of all thanks in advance. I am new to javascript and I am facing an issue with a form that uses javascript to submit values. Everything works great, but the values are submitted as a string delimited by comma, and there is a possibility that the values are submitted have comma on it, so when I explode it on php, I mess up the form input. By example:

**Form input 1:** Highschool, Year 2

**Form input 2:** City

So, the resulting string is: Highschool, Year 2, City
and I need it to be: Highschool, Year 2||City

I can explode it on php and use the values, but no clue how to. I would really appreciate any advice.

Here is the javascript code:

```
function vpb_submit_items()
{
    var vpb_items = [];
    $.each($('.vpb_item'), function() 
    {
        vpb_items.push($(this).val()); 
    });

    if(vpb_items.length == 0 || vpb_items.length == "") 
    { 
        vpb_items = "Empty Field"; 
    } 

    var dataString = "items="+ vpb_items;


        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: ""+dataString+"&date="+date,
```

Thanks again.

Comment: That's not Java, it's Javascript.

Comment: Seems like JavaScript to me :)

Comment: sorry yes, javascript.. editing

Comment: I would recommend using JSON instead of a custom baked format. Would be reasonably easy to just send a JSON string, then parse it in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Array's **[`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** method:

```
var dataString = "items="+ vpb_items.join('||');
```